# How to traverse through XML data in Golang?

Tags: xml, go

I have used xml.UnMarshal method to get a struct object but it has it's own limitations. I need a way where I can get all the descendants of a particular type inside a node without specifying the exact xpath.

For example, I have an xml data of the following format:

```
<content>
    <p>this is content area</p>
    <animal>
        <p>This id dog</p>
        <dog>
           <p>tommy</p>
        </dog>
    </animal>
    <birds>
        <p>this is birds</p>
        <p>this is birds</p>
    </birds>
    <animal>
        <p>this is animals</p>
    </animal>
</content>
```

Now I want to traverse through the above xml and process each node and it's children in that order. The problem is that this structure is not fixed and order of elements may change. So I need a way so that I can traverse like

```
While(Content.nextnode())
{
   switch(type of node)
   {
      //Process the node or traverse the child node deeper
   }
}
```

Comment: Since a solution using only standard lib is presented, in order to not get closed remove the part where you ask for an external library - which is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: The "vanilla encoding" answer is wrong. If you take that struct and pump it back through the encoder (inverse operation), it does not produce the same XML output: https://play.golang.org/p/ynm2WBwTZE

Answer (score 42):

You can do it with a vanilla `encoding/xml` by using a recursive struct and a simple walk function:

```
type Node struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Content []byte `xml:",innerxml"`
    Nodes   []Node `xml:",any"`
}

func walk(nodes []Node, f func(Node) bool) {
    for _, n := range nodes {
        if f(n) {
            walk(n.Nodes, f)
        }
    }
}
```

Playground example: http://play.golang.org/p/rv1LlxaHvK.

---

**EDIT:** Here's a version with attrs:

```
type Node struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Attrs   []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
    Content []byte     `xml:",innerxml"`
    Nodes   []Node     `xml:",any"`
}

func (n *Node) UnmarshalXML(d *xml.Decoder, start xml.StartElement) error {
    n.Attrs = start.Attr
    type node Node

    return d.DecodeElement((*node)(n), &start)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/d9BkGclp-1.

Comment: Clever with the recursive struct, also +1 for doing it only with the standard lib.

Comment: Great, what about attributes?

Comment: Hey, great idea. I am using this to read XML, modify it and now I want to write it back. How would I go about that?

Answer (score 4):

I did a bit of search on how to deal with generic XML DOM and the closest you can do is use `decoder.Token()` or `decoder.RawToken()`.

However if you're willing to consider a library I found this one to be very easy to pick up: https://github.com/beevik/etree

```
doc := etree.NewDocument()
if err := doc.ReadFromFile("bookstore.xml"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

root := doc.SelectElement("bookstore")
fmt.Println("ROOT element:", root.Tag)

for _, book := range root.SelectElements("book") {
    fmt.Println("CHILD element:", book.Tag)
    if title := book.SelectElement("title"); title != nil {
        lang := title.SelectAttrValue("lang", "unknown")
        fmt.Printf("  TITLE: %s (%s)\n", title.Text(), lang)
    }
    for _, attr := range book.Attr {
        fmt.Printf("  ATTR: %s=%s\n", attr.Key, attr.Value)
    }
}
```

It uses the built-in xml parser with in the manner described above.

Answer (score 1):

[xmlquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xquery/) supports parse an XML document as DOM tree to traverse all nodes, like Go's html package.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a library and since it seems you would like to traverse the XML tree, i can recommend [XMLDom-Go](https://bitbucket.org/rj/xmldom-go), i've used it on some past projects.

Comment: I get "repository has been deleted" for the link you provided